# How to convert requests from GET to POST in an application developed using KSH script?

Tags: ksh

We have an application written entirely using KSH script. Some of the GET request parameters carry sensitive data (for e.g. Username, DB name, etc.). We have been instructed to convert those requests from GET to POST. Is it possible to do that now? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: When you have to rewite less than 20 GET commands, do not automate it. When you have more then 100, look for script that helps. Between 20-100 depends on how complicated the lines are and how well your scripting skills are.

Comment: Without examples (input/output) it is very hard to help. When you add your own scripting attempt, it might reveal more specifications of what you want. Nice to see your `sed` or `awk`  attempt.